# Filter a "features" column of Vector type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a program where I need to show specific rows in a Dataset based on certain conditions. These conditions apply to a `features` column I created for a machine learning model. This `features`column is a Vector column, and when I try to filter it by passing a Vector value, I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:75) at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:101)`

This is the filtering part that gives me the error:

`dataset.where(dataset.col("features").notEqual(datapoint)); //datapoint is a Vector`

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a udf for filtering for a Vector. The following worked for me:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6),
  (2, 5, 2), (2, 6, 1), (3, 7, 5), (3, 8, 16),
  (1, 1, 1))).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val dfVec =  new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("c1", "c2", "c3"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .transform(df)

def vectors_unequal(vec1: Vector) = udf((vec2: Vector) => !vec1.equals(vec2))

val vecToRemove = Vectors.dense(1,1,1)

val filtered = dfVec.where(vectors_unequal(vecToRemove)(dfVec.col("features")))  
val filtered2 = dfVec.filter(vectors_unequal(vecToRemove)($"features")) // Also possible
```

`dfVec show` yields:

```
+---+---+---+--------------+
| c1| c2| c3|      features|
+---+---+---+--------------+
|  1|  1|  1| [1.0,1.0,1.0]|
|  1|  2|  3| [1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|  1|  3|  5| [1.0,3.0,5.0]|
|  2|  4|  6| [2.0,4.0,6.0]|
|  2|  5|  2| [2.0,5.0,2.0]|
|  2|  6|  1| [2.0,6.0,1.0]|
|  3|  7|  5| [3.0,7.0,5.0]|
|  3|  8| 16|[3.0,8.0,16.0]|
|  1|  1|  1| [1.0,1.0,1.0]|
+---+---+---+--------------+
```

`filtered show` yields:

```
+---+---+---+--------------+
| c1| c2| c3|      features|
+---+---+---+--------------+
|  1|  2|  3| [1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|  1|  3|  5| [1.0,3.0,5.0]|
|  2|  4|  6| [2.0,4.0,6.0]|
|  2|  5|  2| [2.0,5.0,2.0]|
|  2|  6|  1| [2.0,6.0,1.0]|
|  3|  7|  5| [3.0,7.0,5.0]|
|  3|  8| 16|[3.0,8.0,16.0]|
+---+---+---+--------------+
```